# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory while path seems fine

Tags: php

My project architecture

`./src/index.php`

`./src/Views/App/index.php`

`./src/Views/header.php`

`./src/index.php` is routing and sending the user to `./src/Views/App/index.php`

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
    case '':
        require __DIR__ . '/src/Views/App/index.php';
        break;
```

Then the file simply tries to load the header

```
<?php
    require_once("./../header.php");
?>
```

Even if the relative filepath to header.php looks fine, I'm getting the following error :

Warning: require_once(./../header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rock/Desktop/projets/src/Views/App/index.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './../header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/rock/Bureau/projets/src/Views/App/index.php on line 3

What am I missing there ?

Comment: There is one error in require_once. You are missing one dot, correct is: require_once("../../header.php"); Also your requested index.php looks like to be in on direcotry bellow header.php, so correct should be require_once("../header.php");

Comment: Your way gives the same results. If `.` is the current App directory then `./../` is VIews so I don't think the issue comes from the path itself, there might be something else under the hood that I don't get it there.

Comment: Actually, looks like using `require_once(__DIR__ ."./../header.php");` made the trick; but I don't understand why I need that DIR constant if i'm using relative path, the `.` itself should be enough. If someone has an explanation I take it.

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve]. Also, are you serving from a webserver or using the CLI?